# Junit testing independent Service layer in springboot

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

I have independent service layer packed as jar maven module. Also Dao layer.
(basically 3 projects 1 for controllers, 1 service, 1 dao)

All the configurations and `MainSpringBootApplication.java` is in controller layer. At controller unit tests work just fine with below annotations.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("testenv")
```

Now I want to unit test service layer as well. But facing error.
Service layer class has below annotations

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("testenv")
@PropertySource("classpath:application-testenv")
```

it gives error like below

Same is the case with Dao layer.
How to configure spring for unit test with test.properties file for such project structure.
Note : I am using NO XML configuration.
Any help is appreciated.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.test.example.TestSrevice': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'testService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.example.TestSrevice' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.example.TestSrevice' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 28 more
```

**Edit**
Error trace after suggested changes

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'testDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.example.TestDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.example.TestDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide some test configuration to use with your unit test using the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation. If it's just a `@ComponentScan` you need to use I would recommend just using a static inner class for your configuration in your test class. Annotating your test class with `@ContextConfiguration` with no parameters will default to that inner class for configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("testenv")
@PropertySource("classpath:application-testenv")
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyServiceTest {

  ...

  @ComponentScan
  @Configuration
  public static class MyServiceTestConfiguration {

     @Bean
     public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() {
         return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
     }

  }
}
```

I also included a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean because I'm pretty sure you'll also need that to read your properties correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Plog . Now it says failed to load application context. I have not context xml file. All annotations only

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace to your original question

Comment: Edited the question with original stack trace.

Comment: my project structure is like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/323746/214216

Comment: I meant the new stacktrace with your failed to load application context

Comment: Please check edit part @Plog . It is due to not getting bean of TestDao class which in different module project but dependency is added

Comment: Please add your daily and repository code as well as your configuration classes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your failure below, it confirms that your DAO's aren't being created. Perhaps they aren't being scanned in which case you'd need to ensure the packages do get scanned. If they are getting scanned but the DAOs aren't getting created, the issue may be that JPA isn't loading.

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.test.example.TestDao' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

You may want to add the following annotation to your tests:
`@DataJpaTest`, as specified in the [@DataJpaTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) documentation:

> Annotation that can be used in combination with
>   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) for a typical JPA test. Can be used when
>   a test focuses only on JPA components. Using this annotation will
>   disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration
>   relevant to JPA tests.
>
> By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest will use an embedded
>   in-memory database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured
>   DataSource). The @AutoConfigureTestDatabase annotation can be used to
>   override these settings.
>
> If you are looking to load your full application configuration, but
>   use an embedded database, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined
>   with @AutoConfigureTestDatabase rather than this annotation.

Comment: Thanks @JC Carrillo I am using component scan and providing very basic package now it says it cannot create bean of TestDao because no qualifying bean of testRepositry found. (testRepo is used in testDao). Also tried using `@DataJpaTest` but same error

Comment: Please update your question with the code of both the testRepo and testDao.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Plog and @JC Carrillo I was missing `@DataJpaTest` and additionally `@EntityScan("com.test")` and `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test")` This solved the problem but still my test fails because it is not taking configurations of h2 database from given properties file and boot trys to manage it on its own.